# Docker and net core application doesn't work

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I trying setting up dotnet application with Docker.

**Dockerfile in "backend" folder:**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime 
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./
CMD ["dotnet", "backend.dll"]
```

**Dockerfile in "frontend" folder:**

```
# build
FROM node AS build-env
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN npm run build

# run
FROM nginx

COPY --from=build-env /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**nginx.conf**

```
events {}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }

    location /api {
      rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://api:5000;
    }
  }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  # redis:
  #   image: redis
  #   container_name: demoapp-redis
  # db:
  #   image: postgres
  #   container_name: demoapp-database
  api:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    container_name: demoapp-backend
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    # depends_on:
    #   - db
  web:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    container_name: demoapp-frontend
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - api
```

When I start my application with `dotnet run` all is ok

```
MacBook-Pro-Pavel:~ pavel$ curl http://localhost:5000/values
["value1","value2"]
```

But when I run `docker-compose up` I get this message:

```
demoapp-backend | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
demoapp-backend |       Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: (Error -99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available)
demoapp-backend | Hosting environment: Production
demoapp-backend | Content root path: /app
demoapp-backend | Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
demoapp-backend | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

and when I try to make a request:

```
MacBook-Pro-Pavel:~ pavel$ curl http://localhost:5000/values
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
MacBook-Pro-Pavel:~ pavel$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2ae78ca79f56        demo_web            "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   39 minutes ago      Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       demoapp-frontend
9220206e46fe        demo_api            "dotnet backend.dll"     7 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   demoapp-backend
```

Comment: Can you outline in your code where you are listening on  http://localhost:5000? Your application cannot explicitly bind to 127.0.0.1:5000.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I add `.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")` to my **Program.cs**, thanks [Andy Shinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684908/andy-shinn)